# is it possible to write and design a printable book using html5

Tags: html, css, pdf, mathjax

Im trying to write a book with latex...but I find so hard to "design" the beauty of it... too much plain text with math equations doesn't seem right to me...and even if I finish it, it wouldn't even have a cover because I don't know how to design in latex...just how to write. But I do know HTml5... I was wondering if it might be possible to just design the complete book using mathjax and the versatility of html5 css3 so I can design a beautiful book that might be printable in pdf.

Comment: I think a better format would be PDF. But if you want styling you could make just a really long webpage.

Comment: IMHO the output of a (proper written) latex document is far superior to any other method. Especially in a scientific/technical/mathematical environment it's not about design but about readability. Too much design often distracts from the content. But I'd probably not use latex for writing a children's book.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able but it would be increasing your workload because once you have your finished html5 you'll have to deal with printing it and it won't translate as smoothly. If you would like using css maybe try something like figma, it will print better and give you more control.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

There is CSS specifically for printable views.  For instance, you have the `@media print` media query, and you can specify dimensions in inches (`in`) or centimeters (`cm`), or even points (`pt`).  You also can control where page breaks land, with `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`.

Whether this is practical for *you* and *your project* is a matter of opinion, but the tech certainly makes it possible.  I've never done a book this way, but have done a lot of weird print layouts for things like ID cards, CD labels, faxes, etc.  It's all pretty easy, and I imagine if you're already well-versed in web dev, it might work well for you.

Some more techniques here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing
- https://flaviocopes.com/css-printing/

Comment: Do you know any documentation or tutorial about this?

Comment: @ChristianMichell Aside from the documentation and tutorial I linked to, no.  :-)